# Phase Unwrapping

Tags: continuous-signals, radar, digital, analog

I'm also quite new to world of radar signal processing. I don't understand why we have to make phase unwrapping process. Could you light in me about it? It would be nice conversation speak about it.

I would appreciate if you share useful resources, I am stuck on this. I have read 4-5 articles about detection of human vital signs but Phase unwrapping process was not clearly stated in any of them.

Thanks in advance.

For example, I am following this flowchart, as you can see there is a phase wrapping block but why is it needed? I've seen that we do this because the arctangenct function()'s values are in the range of [-π ,+ π ]. So we need to wrap this signal. but this information is not enough for me to understand.
[image]

Comment: this isn't *generally* the case for radar. I think, but I'm really not sure from your figure, that you're referring to Synthetic Aperture Radar with a range compression scheme. Not all radar is SAR! And not all SAR does this! So, you need to make sure you know which specific part of the radar technology field you're referring to; otherwise it'll be hard to explain the right thing to you :)

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! It's not clear to me from your question what your specific question is.  This site has many questions (some with accepted answers) that deal with the problem of phase unwrapping.  I've closed your question as a duplicate of just one of them (there are many other possible ones).  Please read it, and some of the others, and see if you can be more specific about your question.  If you can, please edit your question and ping me and I'll reopen the question for answers.